# "aws s3 ls" works in Cyberduck but can't list files with the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have the Access Key and Secret Key to a 3rd-party Amazon S3 bucket from which I need to download few files. When I use the Access Key and Secret Key with Cyberduck, all works well and I can list and download files.

However in order to automate the process I need to use the `cp` command through the CLI.

So in the CLI if I do:

```
aws s3 ls
```

it shows me all the bucket names.

However if do this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://list_inside_bucket/
```

then I get the following error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

I verified the Access Key and Secret Key in the `~/.aws/credentials` file and it is perfect.

Comment: check you don't miss anything in the sample: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex0

Comment: Turns out the bucket was not accessible from AWS private subnets.